# Como poner un valor predeterminado al input al enviar formulario?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisiera saber si es posible que al enviar el formulario, un input tenga un valor asignado, en especifíco el que se escribió anteriormente, por ejemplo:

Tengo estos input:

```
<form method="POST" name="ing_cod">
  <input type="text" id="codigo">
  <input type="submit" id="enviar">
</form>
```

Y supongamos que escribo el código "123456". Luego presiono el sumbit y se envía el formulario, y cuando la página refresque para enviar otro código quiero que esté el código antes ingresado o sea "123456" en el `<input type="text" id="código">`, ¿Es posible?

Intenté esto:

```
if(document.ing_cod.submit()){
  var cod = document.querySelector("#codigo").val()
  document.querySelector("codigo").val(cod)
}
```

El código es un asco, pero, ¿exisitirá una manera de poder hacerlo?. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Depende de tu back end. Qué utilizas?

Comment: Javascript y Django, pero principalmente me gustaría realizar esa función con javascrpit puro o jquery, pero por más que intento no dá.

Comment: Si la pagina recarga podrías utilizar sessionStorage o localStorage segun te convenga

Comment: Entonces eso significa que debo interceptar la información durante el envió del primer dato, o sea el código, no?

Comment: Como te dijeron mas arriba debes guardar el input en sessionstorage al envio y debes leer el sessionstorage al refrescar la pagina y asignarselo al value de ese input

Comment: Es necesario recargar la página? Porque de no ser necesario, puedes usar `ajax` para enviar los datos y evitas perder los datos del formulario al no recargar la página.

Comment: Esas son muy buenas ideas, las tomaré en cuenta. Muchas gracias.